# Spark - UnsupportedOperationException when calling Java method from Scala code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, collections

I've implemented code in Scala that is using a method written in Java. 
In the code below `processSale()` is a Java method that takes `util.List<Sale>` as a parameter.

I've converted Scala `Iterable[Sale]` to `Seq[Sale]` and then to `util.List<Sale>` with the help of `scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

```
val parseSales: RDD[(String, Sale)] = rawSales
      .map(sale => sale.Id -> sale)
      .groupByKey()
      .mapValues(a => SaleParser.processSale(a.toSeq.asJava))
```

However when the code gets executed as part of a Spark driver the job fails due to the task failure with `UnsupportedOperationException`. I've looked through the logs and it appears that the reason is within the Java `processSale` method on the call of Collections.sort

```
 Collections.sort(sales, new Comparator<InvocaCall>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Sale sale1, Sale sale2) {
                    return Long.compare(sale1.timestamp, sale2.timestamp);
                }
            });
```

I'm stuck at this point because I'm passing the required `util.List<Sale>`. Why could `Collections.sort` be an unsupported operation in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_46.html):

> Because Java does not distinguish between mutable and immutable
>   collections in their type, a conversion from, say,
>   `scala.immutable.List` will yield a `java.util.List`, where all
>   mutation operations throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`

`toSeq` from your code returns `immutable.Seq`, that's why you get the exception.

So [you can convert](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/BlhW1muOfSo/LjhSCJ8SKD0J) your list to mutable data structure like `ListBuffer`:

```
list.to[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer].asJava
```

Answer (score 1):

Add null check for rawSales `util.List<Sale>`.

```
   val parseSales: RDD[(String, Sale)] = if (rawSales.nonEmpty) 
           //rawSales specific stream operations
          else
           //None or any code as per requirement
```

Comment: Assigning None to RDD?

Comment: @Duelist programmer would decide if they want something at else; otherwise None.